# get the row with the exact owner on react

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
        import React, { useState } from 'react';
        import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        import './App.scss';
        import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
        import ShoesCard from './components/ShoesCard';
        import { Confirmation } from './components/Confirmation';
        import shoes from './data';
        import axios from "axios";
        import { Card, Badge, Button, Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap'
        export default class Shop extends React.Component {

            state = {
                name: "",
                persons: [],
                owner: ''
            };

            constructor() {
                super();
                this.getList();
            }
            handleChange = event => {
                this.setState({ owner: event.target.value });

            }

            getList = event => {
                console.log("in get list");
                axios.get(`${this.state.owner}`)
                    /* axios.get(")*/
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res);
                        this.setState({ persons: [res.data] });
                        console.log("finish set state");
                    });
            };
```

im trying to get the data of array with the owner that have value of 'denmark' on react with axios. i already get all the data on the array but i want to only get the values that have denmark as the owner thank you

Comment: `[].filter` it.

Comment: sorry but im beginner on axios and react, where will i put this? thank you

Comment: So, with axios you get all the data. i can see you are sending owner in the request. Does it give you the filtered data?

Comment: no, i did not get the filtered data. i only get all of the data on the array.

Comment: posted one answer you can check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you get all the data but you required only those which has the owner as ***denmark***. Then you can filter it before setting it to state:

```
console.log(res);
const denmarkData = res.data.filter(obj => obj.owner === this.state.owner); 
//----^^^^^^^^^^^------will be a new Array.
//----and I guessed that obj in "res.data" might have "owner" property.
this.setState({ persons: denmarkData });
```